# Set constraints through code to an element from Storyboard with swift iOS8

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, ios8, nslayoutconstraint

I have a ViewController with a tableView. I've set it up in the Storyboard. Is there a way to set the constraints for the tableView programmatically? I've tried to set a IBOutlet from my tableView in the ViewController and added constraints to it. But that didn't work.

This is my ViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    addTableViewConstraints()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func addTableViewConstraints() {

    tableView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

    var topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.tableView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 20)
    var leadingContraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.tableView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    var trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.tableView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    var bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.tableView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

    self.view.addConstraints([topConstraint, leadingContraint, trailingConstraint, bottomConstraint])

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Cell"
    return cell
}
}
```

Or do I have to make my tableView through code as well?

Thank You!

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in code instead of the in storyboard? Just curious.

Comment: What *didnt* work about your code?

Comment: @keithbhunter I have to change the constraints when i click on a button. And I don't know how to do this if I am doing the constraints in the storyboard.

Comment: @DreamingInBinary it throws an error message in the console: Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

Comment: How will the constraints change when you press the button?

Comment: the topConstraint and bottomConstraint should be changing the constant value to 28 and 8. (old value + 8 )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mentioned in one of your comments that you want to change the constraints when the user presses a button. You can achieve this in less code by making an outlet to the constraint. Find the constraint in the document outline page and CTRL + Drag to your class to create an outlet to the constraint. Then you can change the constant in code easier.

```
@IBOutlet weak var topConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

func buttonPressed() {
    if (/* some condition */) {
        self.topConstraint.constant += 8
        self.bottomConstraint.constant += 8
    } else {
        // Return the constraints to normal, or whatever you want to do
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I'd do as well.  Use the Storyboard to do all the constraints if possible, even to the extend of making placeholders for some, as is the case here.   In this way, you leverage on the Storyboard to check all of your constraints.  It's a better way of "trial and error" than to use code.

Answer (score 5):

Change you method `addTableViewConstraints` in the following way:

```
func addTableViewConstraints() {

   tableView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

   var topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.tableView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 20)
   var leadingContraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.tableView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
   var trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.tableView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
   var bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.tableView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

   NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([topConstraint, leadingContraint, trailingConstraint, bottomConstraint])
}
```

> UPDATE:

The `NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint` constraints that you're running into (and that are causing exceptions) are auto-generated by Interface Builder in order to make your Storyboard or XIB view layout non-ambiguous. It's pretty sneaky about doing this, but it's automatically adding the minimum constraints required so that the position and size of each ambiguous view becomes fully specified.

The way to fix this issue is to add the minimum required constraints in Interface Builder so that each view's position & size is fully specified, then select each of these unwanted constraints, go to the right sidebar Attributes inspector, and check the box next to **Placeholder - Remove at build time**.

I resolved this in the following way:

1. Open up the Storyboard view controller you're handling.
2. Select your `UITableView`.
3. Select the view controller and select **Editor > Resolve Auto Layout Issues > Selected View in [ ] View Controller > Add Missing Constraints** from the menu:

[image]

4. Select all the constraints from your table view:

[image]

1. Check from the right pane the following check box: **Placeholder - Remove at build time**:

[image]

Now you can add all the auto layout constraints manually in your code and without any warnings.

I hope this help you.

Comment: I've tried your answer but I still get an error message in the console 'Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.'

Comment: That's not an error message. That's a warning message.

Comment: @CeceXX Oh sorry for that. But it looks like the tableView doesn't have any constraints, because it appears not the expected way. I've tried the same with setting up the tableView programmatically, and it worked fine. I guess it is not possible to set the tableView in the storyboard and set the constraints for the tableView via code. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a button named `myButton` and you would like to create its `Bottom Space` constraint via code. The `constant` of that constraint will be set to `500`.

Here's what a `NSLayoutConstraint` looks like in Swift. Make sure to include this code in a function.

```
    var constraintButton = NSLayoutConstraint (item: myButton,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom,
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: self.view,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: 500)

    // Add the constraint to the view
    self.view.addConstraint(constraintButton)
```