# Change a constraints constant using code

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, constraints

I am creating this generic base code for all my views, It creates an ad bar that flows across all my pages. I have just included some code from the best answer to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29991246/set-constraints-through-code-to-an-element-from-storyboard-with-swift-ios8) and I cant work out why it doesn't work. I am trying to make it so if the adBanner doesn't load my labels stretch out and take up that space. 
I apologise if this is obvious but I am new to this.
Here is my code

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import iAd


class dayPicker: UIViewController  , ADBannerViewDelegate{

var UIiAd: ADBannerView = ADBannerView()
var SH = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height
var AH = CGFloat()
@IBOutlet var constOne: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var constTwo: NSLayoutConstraint!

func appdelegate() -> AppDelegate {
    return UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    UIiAd.delegate = nil
    UIiAd.removeFromSuperview()
}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(1)
    UIiAd.alpha = 1
    AH = 50
    UIView.commitAnimations()
    self.constOne.constant == 58
    self.constTwo.constant == 58
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(1)
    UIiAd.alpha = 0
    AH = 0
    UIView.commitAnimations()
    self.constOne.constant == 8
    self.constTwo.constant == 8


}
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    UIiAd.delegate = self
    UIiAd = self.appdelegate().UIiAd
    UIiAd.frame = CGRectMake(0, SH - AH , 0, 0)
    self.view.addSubview(UIiAd)

}


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are giving  `==` instead of = while assigning.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import iAd

class dayPicker: UIViewController  , ADBannerViewDelegate{

var UIiAd: ADBannerView = ADBannerView()
var SH = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height
var AH = CGFloat()
@IBOutlet var constOne: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var constTwo: NSLayoutConstraint!

func appdelegate() -> AppDelegate {
    return UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    UIiAd.delegate = nil
    UIiAd.removeFromSuperview()
}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(1)
    UIiAd.alpha = 1
    AH = 50
    UIView.commitAnimations()
    self.constOne.constant = 58
    self.constTwo.constant = 58
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(1)
    UIiAd.alpha = 0
    AH = 0
    UIView.commitAnimations()
    self.constOne.constant = 8
    self.constTwo.constant = 8


}
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    UIiAd.delegate = self
    UIiAd = self.appdelegate().UIiAd
    UIiAd.frame = CGRectMake(0, SH - AH , 0, 0)
    self.view.addSubview(UIiAd)

}


}
```

Comment: I have made the change and it still is not changing the constant to 8. Is there something I need to do in story board to allow this code to replace the default 58 constant I have used in auto layout?

Comment: These two constraints are from interface builder right? how did you add them?

Comment: I added them by control and drag in the storyboard

Comment: I just put the code in view did load and it worked so it must be something to do with the bannerview func

Comment: It turned out to be just a bit hit and miss to force the adbanner to fail, not sure why. I did add a one liner into view will appear to set AH to 50 but that wasn't the solution. Thanks @Amit89 it now works.