# Get "bottom space to superview" constraint on a text field

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I am interested in updating the constraints on one of my text fields so that it moves up in the view. The reason for doing this is so that the text field does not get hidden by the keyboard while it is being edited. I found a SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29992514/887128) that describes how to update the auto-layout constraints on a text field, but it appears to be out of date. What is the correct way to update the constraints on the text field?

I see that `UITextField` has a method `constraints()` that returns a list of constraints, but I am unsure how to identify the correct constraint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using storyboards or xibs to define the UI, you can create an outlet for the constraint you're interested in. If you defined your constraints in code, I'm thinking you should be able to figure out which one you need to modify.

You can modify your constraint and then call something like the following (I just happen to be looking at some of my own code where I had views animate with the keyboard)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillChangeFrame:", name: UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
    ...
}
func keyboardWillChangeFrame(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let frame = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {

        let keyboardHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height - frame.origin.y
        // 8 is the amount of padding I want between the keyboard and button
        self.favoriteButtonBottomMargin.constant = keyboardHeight + 8
        if keyboardHeight > 0.0 {
            self.favoriteButtonBottomMargin.constant -= self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.height ?? 0
        }
    }
    if let duration = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey]?.doubleValue {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have to blindly identify the bottom constraint, you'll need to compare each constraint's items and attributes. For example:

```
var textField: UITextField
var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
if let constraints = textField.constraints() as? [NSLayoutConstraint] {
    for constraint in constraints {
        if (constraint.firstItem == textField && constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom)
            || (constraint.secondItem == textField && constraint.secondAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom) {
                bottomConstraint = constraint
                break
        }
    }
}
bottomConstraint?.constant = 12345
```

Generally, this approach is pretty complicated and gets more complicated if there are potentially other constraints on the view's bottom edge: You'd then have to expand the comparison to look at both items of the constraint and look at the relation value as well.

Your best bet is to assign an IBOutlet property to the constraint that you're trying to modify (or hold onto the constraint in a variable after it's generated). From there, adjust the constraint's `constant` property and call `layoutIfNeeded` as necessary on your parent view.

A much simpler approach you might also consider is transforming the text field by translating it upward when the keyboard comes up, rather than modifying layout.